# Preferred way to call a service more than once in an Angular / Jasmine test

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

Will try to make this brief.  My component gets data from a REST endpoint.  I have a mock service for testing, which I've rigged to give me a different set of data on the 2nd call.

There are some notes in the code below.  I got it to work for one test, but it blows up another test.  I assume there's something shared under the sheets that I'm missing.  It is not this service though.

Component

```
getMessages(): void {
  this.myService.getData()
    .subscribe( (data: MyClass) => {
      this.myClass = data;
      // Do all the things to data
      // Do some stuff w/ the ag-grid api
    });
}

onGridReady(params) {
  // store ag-grid api
  this.gridApi = params.api;
}
```

Then my test

```
beforeEach( () => {
  spyOn(component, 'getMessages').andCallThrough();
});

it('should have data', () => {
  expect(component.myClass).toBeTruthy();
  expect(component.myClass).toEqual('something');

  // All good until here

  // From another answer, but doesn't seem to work:
  // (<jasmine.Spy>component.getMessages).and.callThrough();

  // This works, but blows up another test (makes it throw).
  // Weirdly, they don't share this service. 
  component.getMessages();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.myClass).toEqual('somethingElse');
});
```

Then an unrelated test file which for some reasons starts failing if the last 3 lines of the previous test are uncommented:

```
it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
}
```

Both components use and initialize the gridApi the same way.  Both tests passed always until the aforementioned attempt to load data from a service the second time.

First failure is an uncaught TypeError (I assume from ag-grid), in that it can't find setRowData on undefined. (it's trying this.gridApi.setRowData).  Both tests have the same TestBed configuration and almost mimic each other.  Obviously something set up wrong, which has me asking, would you expect this behavior simply by calling through on function that's been spyOn()'d?   Seems fishy.

Comment: Its really not clear what things are "blown" up. Provide proper error messages and those 2 components (the one which works and the one which doesn't). We cant guess from this much and with no error messages

Comment: Updated: Normally I would assume this is an error with the way i'm doing ag-grid's api loading but they have a pretty in depth guide specifically for Angular & Angular testing which I'm following, then of course I've not seen anything saying how to straight forward call something that runs on a timer.  Still not a veteran at this either though.